# Question involving vector space and linear functionals.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let be $V$ a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$. Lets $p,q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\phi_1,\phi_2, \cdots , \phi_p, \psi_1, \psi_2, \cdots , \psi_q \in V^{*}$. Show that if we have  $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^p (\phi(v))^2 = \sum_{i=1}^q(\psi_i(v))^2$ for all $v \in V$, then $\langle \phi_1,\phi_2,\cdots , \phi_p\rangle = \langle\psi_1 \psi_2, \cdots , \psi_q\rangle$.

I'm trying to solve this exercise, the only thing I can prove is $ \displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^p \ker \phi_i = \bigcap_{i=1}^q \ker \phi_i.$

In fact, let $v \in \displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^p \ker \phi_i$, then $\phi_i(v) = 0, \forall  i=1,2,\cdots,p.$  So, $0 = \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^p (\phi(v))^2 = \sum_{i=1}^q(\psi_i(v))^2$, then $\psi_i(v) = 0, \forall i=1,2,\cdots,q.$ Therefore $\displaystyle \bigcap_{i=1}^p \ker \phi_i \subset \bigcap_{i=1}^q \ker \phi_i.$

We can use the same argument for the otherside.

But it helps??? Can you give me some tips?

Comment: That's it, is it not? $\bigcap_{i=1}^p\ker \phi_i=\bigcap_{j=1}^q\ker\psi_j$ implies $\operatorname{span}(\phi_1,\cdots,\phi_p)=\operatorname{span}(\psi_1,\cdots,\psi_q)$.

Comment: why??  I didn't get that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** From your results so far, you can reach the desired conclusion. Recall that for subspaces $W_1,\dots,W_k \subset V$, we have 
$$
(W_1\cap \cdots \cap W_k)^0 = W_1^0 + \cdots + W_k^0,
$$
where $W^0$ denotes the annihilator subspace $W^0 = \{\phi \in V^*:\phi(x) = 0 \text{ for all }x \in W\}$. Moreover, $W_1 \subset W_2 \implies W_1^0 \supset W_2^0$.

---

A direct proof: define $\Phi:V \to \Bbb R^p$ and $\Psi: V \to \Bbb R^q$ by 
$$
\Phi(v) = (\phi_1(v),\dots,\phi_p(v)), \quad \Psi(v) = (\psi_1(v),\dots,\psi_q(v)).
$$
You have shown that $\ker \Phi = \ker \Psi$. Conclude that $\operatorname{im}(\Phi^*) = \operatorname{im}(\Psi^*)$ (where $\Psi^*: (\Bbb R^p)^* \to V^*$ denotes the dual map). Note that 
$$
\operatorname{im}(\Phi^*) = \langle \phi_1,\dots,\phi_p \rangle, \quad 
\operatorname{im}(\Psi^*) = \langle \psi_1,\dots,\psi_q \rangle,
$$
so we have reached the desired conclusion.

Comment: I understood your answer, thank you!

Comment: @Mathuser You're welcome. Which answer was more useful to you?

Comment: The second is more beautiful and creative than the first :)